# Windows Phone - quick blur effect use on bitmap image in background

Tags: c#, image, silverlight, image-processing, windows-phone

I have cover image for artist that I am using in center of page with 200x200 resolution. I want to repeat this image to background too but change it so user can recognize colors and some shapes that are big. I am not sure which name has this effect in english. I think something as blug, smoothing and something like that.

I found that this block of code do what I want:

```
coverBitmap.ImageOpened += (s, args) =>
{
  var wb = new WriteableBitmap((BitmapImage)s);
  var newHeight = 800;
  wb = wb.Resize(newHeight, newHeight, WriteableBitmapExtensions.Interpolation.Bilinear);
  wb = wb.Crop(new Rect(160, 0, 480, 800));
  wb = wb.Convolute(WriteableBitmapExtensions.KernelGaussianBlur5x5);
  var brush = new ImageBrush {ImageSource = wb};
  LayoutRoot.Background = brush;
};
```

Problem is that with `KernelGaussianBlur5x5` it's still too much sharp (precise). I create my own matrix for 19x19:

```
var array = new[,]
                {
                    {16, 17, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 17, 16},
                    {17, 19, 20, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 20, 19, 17},
                    {19, 20, 22, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 22, 20, 19},
                    {20, 22, 24, 25, 27, 28, 29, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 29, 28, 27, 25, 24, 22, 20},
                    {21, 23, 25, 27, 28, 29, 31, 31, 32, 32, 32, 31, 31, 29, 28, 27, 25, 23, 21},
                    {22, 24, 26, 28, 29, 31, 32, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 32, 31, 29, 28, 26, 24, 22},
                    {23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 32, 33, 34, 34, 35, 34, 34, 33, 32, 31, 29, 27, 25, 23},
                    {24, 26, 28, 30, 31, 33, 34, 35, 35, 36, 35, 35, 34, 33, 31, 30, 28, 26, 24},
                    {24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 36, 36, 35, 34, 33, 32, 30, 28, 26, 24},
                    {24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 33, 35, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 35, 33, 32, 30, 28, 26, 24},
                    {24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 36, 36, 35, 34, 33, 32, 30, 28, 26, 24},
                    {24, 26, 28, 30, 31, 33, 34, 35, 35, 36, 35, 35, 34, 33, 31, 30, 28, 26, 24},
                    {23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 32, 33, 34, 34, 35, 34, 34, 33, 32, 31, 29, 27, 25, 23},
                    {22, 24, 26, 28, 29, 31, 32, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 32, 31, 29, 28, 26, 24, 22},
                    {21, 23, 25, 27, 28, 29, 31, 31, 32, 32, 32, 31, 31, 29, 28, 27, 25, 23, 21},
                    {20, 22, 24, 25, 27, 28, 29, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 29, 28, 27, 25, 24, 22, 20},
                    {19, 20, 22, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 22, 20, 19},
                    {17, 19, 20, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 20, 19, 17},
                    {16, 17, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 17, 16}
                };
```

I am not sure if I created it right. I found example from Microsoft samples from WinForm app and it results `double[,]` so I multiply by 10000 a then save it to `int[,]`. But when I apply this to my code it takes several seconds to create new image and I still want it more blur.

So is there a way how can I fast resize (expand) and crop image and then blur (smudge, smooth) it? Thanks

Comment: Check out the Nokia Imaging SDK http://developer.nokia.com/Develop/Windows_Phone/nokia_apis/imaging.xhtml